# Assign a smarty variable to jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, smarty

I am using the following code to assign a smarty variable into a jquery selector.

```
{literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var prodid = {/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal};

            $( "#option_" + prodid + "_1252" ).change(function() {
                if(4281 == $(this).val()){       
                    //some code    
                }
            });    
        });
    </script>
{/literal}
```

I am probably doing some syntax error because even though I get this right

```
var prodid = 766;
```

in the selector I am getting this

```
$( "#option_" + prodid + "_1252" ).change(function() {
```

instead of this

```
$( "#option_766_1252" ).change(function() {
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're confusing the scope of the back-end php (smarty) template and  browser-side javascript. `$( "#option_" + prodid + "_1252" ).change(function() {` is correct, since javascript will be able to read the dynamically assigned prodid variable within the JS scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unnecessary var declaration within your jquery selector. Try this:

```
$( "#option_" + prodid + "_1252" ).change(function() {
```

Smarty doesn't parse javascript for you so you won't get `$( "#option_766_1252" )` unless you do

```
$( "#option_{/literal}{$product.product_id}{literal}_1252" ).change(function() {
```

Comment: thnx!i get exactly what i wanted!

Comment: OP originally had `$( "#option_" + var prodid + "_1252" ).change(function() {`, but edited it.